Can't read heat pulse sensor data when using ESP32 in station mode
I'm trying to read heart rate data from a pulse sensor and store it in a MySQL database using an ESP32 DevKit C board. However, when I attempt to read data in station mode (Wi-Fi connected), it doesn't work. Can you please help me fix this issue?
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>

#include <PulseSensorPlayground.h>     // Includes the PulseSensorPlayground Library.   

//  Variables
const int PulseWire = 2;       // PulseSensor PURPLE WIRE connected to ANALOG PIN 12
const int LED = LED_BUILTIN;          // The on-board Arduino LED, close to PIN 13.
int Threshold = 550;           // Determine which Signal to "count as a beat" and which to ignore.
                               // Use the "Gettting Started Project" to fine-tune Threshold Value beyond default setting.
                               // Otherwise leave the default "550" value. 
int myBPM =0;                               
                               
PulseSensorPlayground pulseSensor;  // Creates an instance of the PulseSensorPlayground object called "pulseSensor"


String URL = "http://192.168.1.11/sensors_project/insert_data_h.php";

const char* ssid = "";
const char* password = "";


void setup() {   

  Serial.begin(115200);          // For Serial Monitor

  connectWiFi();  //Connect to the network

  // Configure the PulseSensor object, by assigning our variables to it. 
  pulseSensor.analogInput(PulseWire);   
  pulseSensor.blinkOnPulse(LED);       //auto-magically blink Arduino's LED with heartbeat.
  pulseSensor.setThreshold(Threshold);   

  // Double-check the "pulseSensor" object was created and "began" seeing a signal. 
   if (pulseSensor.begin()) {
    Serial.println("We created a pulseSensor Object !");  //This prints one time at Arduino power-up,  or on Arduino reset.  
  }
}



void loop() {

 
  if(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    connectWiFi();
  }

  if (pulseSensor.sawStartOfBeat()) {            // Constantly test to see if "a beat happened".
    myBPM = pulseSensor.getBeatsPerMinute();  // Calls function on our pulseSensor object that returns BPM as an "int".
                                                  // "myBPM" hold this BPM value now. 
    Serial.println("♥  A HeartBeat Happened ! "); // If test is "true", print a message "a heartbeat happened".
    Serial.print("BPM: ");                        // Print phrase "BPM: " 
    Serial.println(myBPM);                        // Print the value inside of myBPM. 
  }

  String postData = "heartbeat=" + String(myBPM);
  
  HTTPClient http;
  http.begin(URL);
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  
  int httpCode = http.POST(postData);
  String payload = "";
  if(httpCode > 0) {
    // file found at server
    if(httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK) {
      String payload = http.getString();
      Serial.println(payload);
    } else {
      // HTTP header has been send and Server response header has been handled
      Serial.printf("[HTTP] GET... code: %d\n", httpCode);
    }
  } else {
    Serial.printf("[HTTP] GET... failed, error: %s\n", http.errorToString(httpCode).c_str());
  }
  
  http.end();  //Close connection

  delay(200);                    // considered best practice in a simple sketch.

}

void connectWiFi() {
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_OFF);
  delay(1000);
  //This line hides the viewing of ESP as wifi hotspot
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi");
  
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
    
  Serial.print("connected to : "); Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.print("IP address: "); Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

  

Once I fix the issue with reading data in station mode, I will be able to continuously monitor a person's heart rate and store the readings in a MySQL database.
